# TikZ - node along a path at the intersection of the path it's on with another path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Can this node at intersection `a` be drawn along the `\draw` path rather than what I did using an additional `\node` command? i.e. compacting this into one line rather than two?

[image: Intersection 'a']

### MWE

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [node distance = 2cm,
     block/.style={draw, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, align=center},
     >={latex}
    ]

    % Main blocks
    \node [block, dashed, minimum size=5cm, name path=box]  (box)   {};
    \node [block, anchor=west] (internalblock) {internal\\block};
    \node [block, above=of box.north west, anchor=west] (externalblock) {external\\block};
    
    % Arrows
    \draw[->, name path=curve 1] ($ (internalblock.north) - (.5cm,0) $) -- ++(0,3cm) -| (externalblock);
    \node[rectangle, fill=white, font=\bfseries, name intersections={of=box and curve 1, by={a}}] at (a) {a};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `intersections` library was created for this purpose (implementing the intersection in a standalone command). I can easily imagine that there were no alternatives, or otherwise it wouldn't be a library.

Comment: My way to approach this is, I never use `anchor=?` and `above=of ?`. And I always use integral coordinates for paths and node positions. If I need an intersection, that intersection is of integral coordinates, too. So I would just write down `(3, 5)node{a}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [node distance = 2cm,
     block/.style={draw, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, align=center},
     >={latex}
    ]

    % Main blocks
    \node [block, dashed, minimum size=5cm]  (box)   {};
    \node [block, anchor=west] (internalblock) {internal\\block};
    \node [block, above=of box.north west, anchor=west] (externalblock) {external\\block};
    
    % Arrows
    \draw[->] ([xshift=-0.5cm] internalblock.north)   -- ++(0,3cm) -| (externalblock) ([xshift=-0.5cm] internalblock.north |- 0,2.5cm)  node[rectangle, fill=white, font=\bfseries] {a};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Diagram with three boxes]

Comment: This is perfect! Instead of the perpendicular intersection using a specific coordinate like `0,2.5cm`, I used `([xshift=-0.5cm] internalblock.north |- box.north)`

Comment: Yes - even better

Comment: There is a difference though. The arrowhead is gone.

Comment: Yes - I did not notice. It is much better to draw the arrow first instead of insisting on making it in one line and then add the node after: `\node[rectangle, fill=white, font=\bfseries] at ([xshift=-0.5cm] internalblock.north |- box.north)  {a};`

Comment: Oneline: `\draw[->] ([xshift=-0.5cm] internalblock.north |- box.north)  node[rectangle, fill=white, font=\bfseries] {a} ([xshift=-0.5cm] internalblock.north) -- ++(0,3cm) -| (externalblock);
`